# <?= and <? echo in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo, fuelphp, shorthand

I'm using PHP frameworks like codeigniter and fuelphp, I read some of it's manual that i's recommending `<?=` over `<?php echo`. But I don't use both of them, instead I'm using `<? echo`, but I'm still not sure if I'm doing it right. I don't feel comfortable using `<?=`. Need advice from experienced PHP developers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP <?= vs <?php echo What's the difference? Which one is better to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847072/php-vs-php-echo-whats-the-difference-which-one-is-better-to-use)

Comment: `I'm using <? echo` it would not work. Btw always use `<?php ?>` .feel comfortable.

Comment: you can use `<=`  but you also have to set the true of short syntax in php.ini file. then that will be equal to echo otherwise it will prompt error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right or wrong for this, it's an opinion based matter. I personally do like to use shorttags when I can because I find it easier to read. Others might find the

```
 <?php
```

easier to read and will prefer this. It's a fully opinion based matter and I wouldnt worry about it. Use which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has deprecated the use of `<?`
as it has been adopted by other programming langs

It's recommended to use `<?php` if you feel confortable.

Enjoy your coding...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `<? ... ?>`  is the short code of `<?php ... ?>`... Here's what it says from the PHP Documentation itself:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

> #### short_open_tag boolean
>
> Tells PHP whether the short form () of PHP's open tag should be allowed. If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use  inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example: '; ?>. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag ().

To have that working on your server, the `short_open_tag` must be enabled in your `php.ini`. There's no right or wrong way of writing it, but some people prefer the old long way `<?php ... ?>`, such as me, because I find it easier to read.

Same thing for the `<?=`, here's what the PHP Documentation say

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

For more information about echo:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Note that on a lot of servers, short_open_tags are disabled, so if you don't maintain your own server, it is safer to not rely on this feature.